# Refused connection in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, swing, exception, jdbc

Here is my connecting function:

```
public void connect(){
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=qlsv";
        String user = "sa";
        String password = "21@MaiChiTam07";
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected Successfully!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

And here is my exception. Can anyone help me?

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2369)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:551)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1962)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1627)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1458)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:772)
    at sqljdbc42/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
    at JDBC/DSLopHoc.Database.connect(Database.java:20)
    at JDBC/DSLopHoc.UILopHoc.<init>(UILopHoc.java:116)
    at JDBC/DSLopHoc.UILopHoc.lambda$0(UILopHoc.java:192)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I set my firefall allow TCP/IP and port 1433 but it's not help at all.

Comment: Is your server running on port 1433? Check SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Hope that is not your real password. If it is you better change it - cos it's here forever now

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using `sa` in your application.

Comment: `sqljdbc42` are you seriously using this old hat driver? Why not try a bit fresher one from microsoft, even jtds is better than that dinosaur

Comment: At least `sqljdbc42` had an update in 2018 so, no, jTDS isn't better. :)

Comment: Second checking the current network protocol configurations in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager. SQL Server Express instances typically listen on random port numbers - if they even have the TCP/IP server protocol enabled at all. If you change/fix the protocol configurations here be sure to restart the SQL Server instance for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i meant jtds was better than 4.2 ms driver, not newer :) But yeah, both are old now